# Finding the majority element in an array using C using Divide and Conquer

Tags: c, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Im writing an algorithm for finding a majority element in an array. Basically, if an element appears at least length/2 in an array, its a majority element. Otherwise, the array has no majority element.

Im not well versed in C, so I found the same solution in Python, and tried to convert it. However, the results I get have some unusual errors. My algorithm is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int find_majority_element(int arr[], int length);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 12, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 9, 6, 2, 1, 2 };
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    int result = find_majority_element(arr, length);

    if (result == -1) {
        printf("None");
    } else {
        printf("%d", result);
    }
    return 0;
}

int find_majority_element(int arr[], int length) {

    if (length == 2) {
        if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
            return arr[0];
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else if (length == 1) {
        return arr[0];
    }

    int *leftHalf = arr;
    int *rightHalf = arr + length/2;

    int element1 = find_majority_element(leftHalf, length/2);
    int element2 = find_majority_element(rightHalf, length/2);

    if (element1 == -1 && element2 >= 0) {
        return element2;
    } else if (element2 == -1 && element1 >= 0) {
        return element1;   
    }

    if (element1 == element2) {
        return element1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

This gives me unexpected results, which is weird considering the fact that I just converted another algorithm. The algorithm in question can be found here:

[Link](https://github.com/MrDupin/Algorithms/blob/master/Divide%20and%20Conquer/FindMajorityElement.py)

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT

For the given input, the majority element is shown to be 2. Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "giv[ing] me unexpected results"? What do you expect, and can you show the output?

Comment: unexpected how? what is expected, what did you get? (note: your code looks neat)

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: 1) Not sure the logic is sound. `[0, 1, 0, 1]` would give no majority number, when you have actually two (unless you meant `frequency > length/2`, not `>=`). On the other hand, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]` would give 6 as majority number? 2) When you divide, you assume length is always even; it should be `int element2 = find_majority_element(rightHalf, length/2 + (length % 2));`.

Comment: Agree that the Python algorithm is not correct. And majority element is usually defined as one that appears > `length/2` times.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes I have tried a few things. But it simply does not work. I was obviously under the assumption that the Python algo was correct, which may not be the case.

Comment: @jdehesa I have tried adding the change you mentioned, it fixes the error when length is even only. Otherwise, its the wrong output.

Comment: the algorithm works for sorted arrays, so you should either sort it before execution or you need to create a new algorithm. @jdehesa comment is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is not checking the entire right half when `length` is odd. [@jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987778/finding-the-majority-element-in-an-array-using-c-using-divide-and-conquer#comment84980429_48987778)

```
// int element2 = find_majority_element(rightHalf, length/2);
int element2 = find_majority_element(rightHalf, length - length/2);
```

OP's approach, overall, is incorrect for an *unsorted* array [@Dagan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987778/finding-the-majority-element-in-an-array-using-c-using-divide-and-conquer/48993101#comment84983001_48987778).  Review [Majority Element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/) for alternate solutions.

---

Pedantic corner: code has trouble with `length <= 0`.